# Imageview and PagerAdapter

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I want to put images in each pages of my ViewPager (like a book). Those images came from a list of url :

My Adapter looks like this :

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }

/**
 * Create the page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
 * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
 * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
 * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
 *
 * @param container The containing View in which the page will be shown.
 * @param position The page position to be instantiated.
 * @return Returns an Object representing the new page.  This does not
 * need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.
 */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        // Create Views
        ScrollView view = new ScrollView(cxt);
        RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(cxt);
        TextView text = new TextView(cxt);
        text.setId(1);
        ImageView[] image = new ImageView[18];
        // Parameters
        LayoutParams container_params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        LayoutParams text_params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        LayoutParams content_params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        content_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, text.getId());

        view.setLayoutParams(container_params);
        container.setLayoutParams(container_params);
        text.setLayoutParams(text_params);
        //image.setLayoutParams(content_params);

        // set

        for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
            image[i] = new ImageView(cxt);
            image[i].setLayoutParams(content_params);
            createimage(image[i], list_url.get(position));
            container.addView(image[i]);
        }
        text.setText(list_url.get(position).toString());
        // add
        view.addView(container);
        container.addView(text);
        //container.addView(image);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

/**
 * Remove a page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
 * for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
 * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
 *
 * @param container The containing View from which the page will be removed.
 * @param position The page position to be removed.
 * @param object The same object that was returned by
 * {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
 */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((ScrollView) view);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view==((ScrollView)object);
    }


/**
 * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed.  At this
 * point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been added or
 * removed from the container as appropriate.
 * @param container The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
 * page views.
 */
    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

}
```

and i take those images thanks to a asynctask :

```
private class CreateImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
ImageView image;
public CreateImage(ImageView img) {
    image = img;
}
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
    InputStream is;
    Drawable d = null ;
    try {
        is = (InputStream)new URL(urls[0]).getContent();
        d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "Image");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return d;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable d) {
    image.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url) { 
    try {
     URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
     InputStream is = (InputStream) imageUrl.getContent();
     Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
     return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
    }
   }
}
public void createimage(ImageView img, String url){
new CreateImage(img).execute(url);
}
```

the thing is that it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry it was a mistake but wow i can't even describe -> I didn't put the Permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and i put

```
d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicWidth());
```

int the onPostExecute because i didn't want the images to be all weird.

Answer (score 2):

`for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
            image[i] = new ImageView(cxt);
            image[i].setLayoutParams(content_params);
            createimage(image[i], list_url.get(position));
            container.addView(image[i]);
        }`

I don't think you have to do it in a for loop. You can perhaps look at the sample in compatibility library. I think it automatically instantiate an item for a position. Here is an sample I found after googling-

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(cxt);
        tv.setText("Bonjour PAUG " + position);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setTextSize(30);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(tv,0);

        return tv;
    }
```

Comment: I know this example because it was the one i replace by. Now i used a layout inflater to inflate a custom view, but it's still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used a `PagerAdapter` before but I doubt you can return a view in `instantiateItem` and then only after download the resource (in the `AsyncTask`). When the `AsyncTask` sets the background image, I think it's too late, the adapter has already returned the view...

You'll probably need to invalidate the view at some point...

Comment: okay, that's why, i left a Toast in the onPostExecute and it appeared. But how can i invalidate the view ?

Comment: Simply with [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()).

Comment: i tried to invalidate view but it didn't work at all, i tried to invalidateDrawable in the Asynctask, it didn't work either.

Comment: That's the `Pager` you should invalidate. This will imply that the `PagerAdapter` queries `getView()` on all items again. Hence, you should keep the corresponding file in cache, and provide it synchronously.

Comment: Mb `notifyDatasetChanged()` on adapter?

Comment: I think @rds is right. You cannot invalidate the view after `instantiateItem()` has completed. The images need to be downloaded and cached *before* `instantiateItem()` is called.